# ActionCable: Detect connection lost on client side, show connection status to user

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, websocket, ping, actioncable

Is there a way to be notified or detect the state of a websocket connection on the client side of an app? ActionCable already implements a 3 second-period ping from server->client, and [there is certainly client-side functionality](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actioncable/app/assets/javascripts/action_cable/connection_monitor.coffee) that uses this ping to detect connection status, but how do I propagate this information to my app? I want to be able to show connection status to the user, preferably without implementing my own pinging, as that would be superfluous.

Comment: I'm looking for the solution to the same above question. How did you resolve it? Where do you find disconnected() in mychannel.coffee? Your link client-side above has no content.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, nevermind, that's the disconnected() method in mychannel.coffee, of course. Sorry, I'm quite new to this stuff.